# Sending data through axios post gives null data in mysql.Can anyone tell me what is the problem

Tags: mysql, reactjs, spring-boot, axios

```
export class AddCategory extends Component {
    state = {
        categoryForm: {
            category: {
                elementType: 'input',
                elementConfig: {
                    type: 'text',
                    placeholder: 'Enter Category'
                },
                value: '',
                validation: {
                    required: true
                },
                valid: false,
                touched: false
            }
        }
    };

    checkValidity(value, rules) {
        let isValid = true;

        if (!rules) {
            return true;
        }

        if (rules.required) {
            isValid = value.trim() !== '' && isValid;
        }

        return isValid;
    }
    inputChangedHandeller = (event, controlNameOne) => {
        const copyLoginFrom = {
            ...this.state.categoryForm,
        };
        const newCopy = {
            ...copyLoginFrom[controlNameOne]
        };
        newCopy.value = event.target.value;
        newCopy.valid = this.checkValidity(newCopy.value, newCopy.validation);
        newCopy.touched = true;
        copyLoginFrom[controlNameOne] = newCopy;
        let formIsValid = true;
        for (let inputIdentifier in copyLoginFrom) {
            formIsValid = copyLoginFrom[inputIdentifier].valid && formIsValid;
        }
        this.setState({
            categoryForm: copyLoginFrom,
            formIsValid: formIsValid
        });
    }

    dataPost = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const formData = {};
        for (let addressData in this.state.categoryForm) {
            formData[addressData] = this.state.categoryForm[addressData].value;
        }
        const newAddress = {
            newAddressData: formData
        }
        console.log("Hello......." + newAddress);
        const parentId = this.state.parent_id;
        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
            },
            data: formData,
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/admin/category/'
        }
        axios(options);
    }
    render() {
        const formElementsArray = []; //converting state object to the array I can loop throuh
        for (let key in this.state.categoryForm) {
            formElementsArray.push({
                id: key,
                config: this.state.categoryForm[key]
            });
        }

        let form = ( <
            form onSubmit = {
                this.dataPost
            } > {
                formElementsArray.map(forElement => ( <
                    Input key = {
                        forElement.id
                    }
                    elementType = {
                        forElement.config.elementType
                    }
                    elementConfig = {
                        forElement.config.elementConfig
                    }
                    value = {
                        forElement.config.value
                    }
                    invalid = {
                        !forElement.config.valid
                    }
                    shouldValidate = {
                        forElement.config.validation
                    }
                    touched = {
                        forElement.config.touched
                    }
                    elementGet = {
                        (event) => this.inputChangedHandeller(event, forElement.id)
                    }
                    />
                ))
            }

            <
            button className = "btn btn-primary"
            disabled = {
                !this.state.formIsValid
            } > Submit < /button> <
            /form>
        )
        return ( <
            div >
            <
            div className = {
                styles.Login
            } > {
                form
            } <
            /div> <
            /div>
        )
    }
}
```

**I am trying to send data using axios but the output I am getting in mysql table is Null.Can anyone tell me what is the problem with my code.I tried printing the sent data on console and output I am getting is [object Object] I tried using stringify method but It gives error of header while posting data**

Answer (score 0):

try qs which is a query string parser:

```
npm install qs
```

and then :

```
 import qs from "qs"

// in your body 

     const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
               'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' // need to add content type
            },
            data: qs.stringify(formData),
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/admin/category/'
        }
```

Comment: I am getting this error please have a look after applying qs to my code.        TypeError: qs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default.a.stringfy is not a function. (In 'qs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default.a.stringfy(formData)', 'qs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default.a.stringfy' is undefined)

Comment: sorry its `qs.stringify` not `qs.stringfy`

Comment: Still facing issue getting error   Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Comment: add the content type to header like so: `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }`

Comment: Any other approach it is still not working getting 304 not modified

Comment: where you are getting the error on server or on the front app ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215457/discussion-between-adel-and-user5474425).